# Restricting Access to S3 to a Specific IP Address

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have a bucket policy that I customized from the AWS S3 docs, instead of range of IP addresses, I changed it for just one IP. The bucket name is : www.joaquinamenabar.com. The IP address 66.175.217.48 corresponds to the sub-domain: https://letsdance.joaquinamenabar.com/

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Id": "S3PolicyId1",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "IPAllow",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": "*",
      "Action": "s3:*",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::www.joaquinamenabar.com/*",
      "Condition": {
         "IpAddress": {"aws:SourceIp": "66.175.217.48"},
         "NotIpAddress": {"aws:SourceIp": "66.175.217.48"} 
      } 
    } 
  ]
}
```

The files are not available for public. I generate links using aws-sdk that expires after some time. The problem is the link is accessible from any IP. It has been more than a week since I changed the configuration. The changes should have propagated by this time. Any ideas what is wrong with this configuration?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the effect of this policy is to allow access from all IP's (66.175.217.48 and not 66.175.217.48).  Remove the NotIpAddress specifier.  I think you may need to specify the allowed Ip address in CIDR format too:

```
"IpAddress": {"aws:SourceIp": "66.175.217.48/32"}
```