# Deny access to AWS S3 to all IPs except specific ranges

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, acl, amazon-iam

I hava an S3 Bucket ("myBucket"), to which only a user has access, let's call it "s3user". I have an IAM policy attached to this user as follows:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:ListBucket",
                "s3:GetBucketLocation"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::myBucket"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor1",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:ListBucket",
                "s3:GetObjectVersion"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

I attached this IAM Policy to user "s3User", granting read-only access to "myBucket". So far so good.

Now, I added a second policy, but now not an IAM policy but an S3 Bucket Policy, as follows:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "S3PolicyId1",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "IPAllow",
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::myBucket/*",
            "Condition": {
                "NotIpAddress": {
                    "aws:SourceIp": [
                        "1.2.3.4/27",
                        "2.3.4.1/28",
                        "5.6.7.8/29"
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

I expected that this explicit deny will deny all requests not coming from the specified source IP ranges. But, it is still letting me list the contents of the bucket from other IPs. It seems as if the bucket policy had no effect at all.

According to [this AWS S3 article](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/iam-policies-and-bucket-policies-and-acls-oh-my-controlling-access-to-s3-resources/), when you have multiple policies, they are all applied and explicit denies have precedence over explicit allows, so I think this *should* be working, but it isn't.

Any ideas why I'm not able to deny requests to a bucket based on sourceIP addresses?

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by "letting me access the bucket from other IPs"? Which commands, specifically? The `Deny` policy refers to `mybucket/*` and might not apply to `mybucket` alone, so `ListBucket` might still be permitted.

Comment: I meant I can still list the contents of the bucket (edited the question to clarify this)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should update your `Deny` policy to include operations that are performed on the bucket itself, rather than its content (`/*`):

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "S3PolicyId1",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "DenyOutsideIPfromBucket",
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": [
                "s3:ListBucket",
                "s3:GetBucketLocation",
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:ListBucket",
                "s3:GetObjectVersion"
            ],
            "Resource": ["arn:aws:s3:::myBucket/*", "arn:aws:s3:::myBucket"],
            "Condition": {
                "NotIpAddress": {
                    "aws:SourceIp": [
                        "1.2.3.4/27",
                        "2.3.4.1/28",
                        "5.6.7.8/29"
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Of course, if the only users with access to the bucket are the ones with the IAM policy, you could simply add a `IpAddress` condition on the original IAM policy, so they can only use the bucket from the given set of IP addresses. This would avoid the need for a `Deny` policy.

Comment: Thanks, will check if this works on Monday and let you know.

Comment: Update: it worked. I edited your answer to declare both resources (bucket and its contents) in the same declaration to avoid duplicating IP addresses.

Comment: Hello @John,

We also have a similar requirement. That a user needs read-only access to an S3 bucket and we have applied below IAM policy to the user as you suggested we have not applied any bucket policy since this is the only user with specific IP address. Stil it doesn't work. Please suggest

Comment: `{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:ListBucket"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::marketplace-logs",
                "arn:aws:s3:::marketplace-logs/*",
            ],
            "Condition": {
                "IpAddress": {
                    "aws:SourceIp": "13.xxx.xxx.xxx/32"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}`

Comment: @nitin194 Please create a new question rather than asking a question via a comment on an old question.

Comment: Sure John here it is [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51350398/restricting-access-to-s3-to-a-specific-ip-address)